# Making a proper tabbed interface in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tabs, user-experience

I'm writing an application with JavaFX that will use tabs. Users may want to have tabs open beside each other at the same time (instead of just one tab at a time). This would ideally be achieved by dragging a tab to a side of the screen.

Originally I thought that it might be a good idea to make a grid panel with just one grid, then add grids as users drag tabs around. I don't think that'll work. Is there a good way to do this? Are JavaFX's layout and pane controls really this lacking?

In C# I might have used something like this for the intended behaviour I want: http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

The question: how can I achieve a proper UX with tabs in JavaFX, allowing the user to drag tabs to have a "split" layout?

EDIT: At the moment I'm thinking of trying to replicate my above idea but with an HBox. Does anyone know how I could implement tab dragging to another quadrant in an HBox?

Comment: There's nothing predefined. There may be some third-party libraries that implement something like this (e.g. I think [Drombler](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/) has docking functionality). Otherwise you would just have to implement it yourself with the appropriate mouse handlers, etc.

Comment: I don’t think this is possible with a TabPane, since you can’t know on which Tab a mouse action takes place.  I would probably create “fake” tabs using ToggleButtons, and I would use a StackPane for the content area, binding the visibility of each tab content node to a particular ToggleButton’s selected state.

Comment: @VGR Another workaround is to use a `Label` as the graphic on a `Tab` (instead of setting the tab's text), and register the mouse handler with the label. (Or write a new `TabPaneSkin`, if you are feeling *really* ambitious.)

Comment: There's plenty of libs, just search for detachable tabpane. eg. http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/2015/09/18/detachabletabpane-supports-docking-and-reordering/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So your question is a bit vague and I probably shouldn't be answering it as honestly I really have no idea what "a proper tabbed interface" really means.

Here is a system which allows tabs to be open beside each other.  Right click on a tab to bring up a context menu to choose to split vertically or horizontally.  The tab content will be replicated within a new TabPane inside a SplitPane in the desired orientation.

This is definitely not a full docking solution and perhaps not even close to what you want, but maybe you find it useful (maybe not ;-).  The solution just accomplishes the splitting, but not dragging and dropping of tabs between the split regions (perhaps [get in contact with Tom Schindl](https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2014/05/12/e4-on-javafx-drag-and-drop-between-stacks-javafx-tabpanes/) for info on the drag and drop part if you can't figure it out yourself).

The solution below just copies the content of a split tab to a new tab in the new split zone.  Further enhancements could enact something like a common synced document model which allowed side-by-side editing of files duplicated in different tabs (similar to Intellij Idea's editor implementation from which this split system concepts were derived).

[image: sample]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SplitTabs extends Application {
    final Lorem lorem = new Lorem();

    final HashMap<Node, SplitPane> splitPanes = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
        IntStream.range(0, 5)
                .mapToObj(i -> createTab(lorem.nextString(1), lorem.nextString(200)))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(tabPane::getTabs));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(tabPane)));
        stage.show();
    }

    private Tab createTab(String title, String text) {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea(text);
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

        Tab tab = new Tab(title);
        tab.setContent(textArea);
        tab.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            TabPane tabPane = tab.getTabPane();
            if (tabPane.getTabs().size() <= 1) {
                SplitPane splitPane = splitPanes.get(tabPane);
                if (splitPane == null) {
                    // don't allow the last tab to be closed.
                    event.consume();
                    return;
                }

                int siblingIdx = (splitPane.getItems().indexOf(tabPane) + 1) % 2;
                Node siblingItem = splitPane.getItems().get(siblingIdx);


                Optional<SplitPane> optionalParentSplitPane =
                        splitPanes.values().stream()
                                .filter(searchPane -> searchPane.getItems().contains(splitPane))
                                .findFirst();

                // make the last TabPane the root.
                if (!optionalParentSplitPane.isPresent()) {
                    StackPane stackPane = (StackPane) splitPane.getParent() ;
                    stackPane.getChildren().setAll(siblingItem);
                    splitPanes.clear();
                    return;
                }

                // graft sibling under parent.
                SplitPane parentSplitPane = optionalParentSplitPane.get();

                int idx = parentSplitPane.getItems().indexOf(splitPane);
                parentSplitPane.getItems().set(idx, siblingItem);
                splitPane.getItems().forEach(splitPanes::remove);
                splitPanes.put(siblingItem, parentSplitPane);
            }
        });

        MenuItem splitVertically = new MenuItem("Split Vertically");
        splitVertically.setOnAction(event -> split(title, text, tab, Orientation.HORIZONTAL));
        MenuItem splitHorizontally = new MenuItem("Split Horizontally");
        splitHorizontally.setOnAction(event -> {
            split(title, text, tab, Orientation.VERTICAL);
        });

        tab.setContextMenu(new ContextMenu(
                splitVertically,
                splitHorizontally
        ));

        return tab;
    }

    private void split(String title, String text, Tab tab, Orientation orientation) {
        TabPane tabPane = tab.getTabPane();
        Tab tabCopy = createTab(title, text);
        TabPane newTabPane = new TabPane(tabCopy);
        SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane(tabPane, newTabPane);
        splitPane.setOrientation(orientation);

        if (splitPanes.isEmpty()) {
            StackPane stackPane = (StackPane) tabPane.getParent();
            stackPane.getChildren().setAll(splitPane);
            splitPanes.put(tabPane, splitPane);
            splitPanes.put(newTabPane, splitPane);
        } else {
            SplitPane parentSplit = splitPanes.get(tabPane);
            int idx = parentSplit.getItems().indexOf(tabPane);
            parentSplit.getItems().set(idx, splitPane);
            splitPanes.remove(tabPane);
            splitPanes.put(splitPane, parentSplit);
            splitPanes.put(tabPane, splitPane);
            splitPanes.put(newTabPane, splitPane);
        }
    }
}

class Lorem {
    private static final String[] IPSUM = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque hendrerit imperdiet mi quis convallis. Pellentesque fringilla imperdiet libero, quis hendrerit lacus mollis et. Maecenas porttitor id urna id mollis. Suspendisse potenti. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras lacus tellus, semper hendrerit arcu quis, auctor suscipit ipsum. Vestibulum venenatis ante et nulla commodo, ac ultricies purus fringilla. Aliquam lectus urna, commodo eu quam a, dapibus bibendum nisl. Aliquam blandit a nibh tincidunt aliquam. In tellus lorem, rhoncus eu magna id, ullamcorper dictum tellus. Curabitur luctus, justo a sodales gravida, purus sem iaculis est, eu ornare turpis urna vitae dolor. Nulla facilisi. Proin mattis dignissim diam, id pellentesque sem bibendum sed. Donec venenatis dolor neque, ut luctus odio elementum eget. Nunc sed orci ligula. Aliquam erat volutpat.".split(" ");
    private int idx = 0;

    public String nextString(int nWords) {
        int end = Math.min(idx + nWords, IPSUM.length);

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = idx; i < end; i++) {
            result.append(IPSUM[i]).append(" ");
        }

        idx += nWords;
        idx = idx % IPSUM.length;

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll set this as the answer for now since it's better than what I've got. I'm baffled that there isn't a better solution. I guess nobody wants tabbed documents up beside each other?

Comment: Well there is stuff (see the solutions linked in other comments), I just don't know if any of them are what you are looking for.

Comment: I think for full-blown desktop docking interface and application frameworks, Swing and SWT has been around a while and people have created lots of stuff for that (e.g. https://netbeans.org/features/platform/, https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.platform, http://www.jetbrains.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=983889).  You can use JavaFX inside either of those, so rather than create new platforms of that magnitude in JavaFX, it may be simpler to embed your JavaFX program inside those platforms, though coding to such platforms requires a fairly high level of sophistication.